# Issue with removing LI using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

i am making navigation bar using `<ul>` and `<li>`

i first data like (html)

```
  <ul id="menu_xml_txt">
     <li id="1"> Root Catalog </li>
 </ul>
```

when click on `Root Catalog` it will replace this all `<li>` it will like

```
<ul id="menu_xml_txt">
 <li id="2">Apparel</li> 
 <li id="3">Accessories</li>
</ul>
```

and so on. when you click it will changed and replaced by all new `<li>`

when you click on `<li>` it will added to a `div=reg_navlist` i am using `.append` of jquery function

then it will like

```
<ul id="reg_navlist">
 <li id="1">Root Catalog</li>  
 <li id="3">Accessories</li> 
 <li id="45">bla bla..</li> 
 <li id="80">bla bla..</li> 
 <li id="95">bla bla..</li> 
 <li id="115">bla bla..</li> 
 </ul>
```

i want to remove only those `<li>` element which is i have clicked & li and coming after it
for example if i have clicked on where `<li id=45>` then the id=45 and id= 80, id=95, and id=115 will be removed not the id=1 and id=3

i have tried this jQuery code

```
 j('#region_navlist li').live('click', function() {
    var cliked_id = j(this).attr('id');
    j('#region_nav li:not(:first)').remove();
});
```

but it is removing all the `<li>` not the first one

Comment: Have a look at [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), also you should not start an `id` with a number: `For example, id and name attributes must begin with a letter, not a digit.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do:

```
j('#region_navlist li').on('click', function() {
    j(this).nextAll().andSelf().remove();
});
```

See: [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) and [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
Note:- .live() is deprecated you use .on() if version 1.7
```